# Primefaces removing uploaded file

Tags: primefaces

I am using the following code to remove the file uploaded using primefaces.

```
<p:column width="35" headerText="Delete" style="text-align:center">
    <h:commandLink ajax="true" update="@form" title="Delete Document"
        process="@form" action="#{learningGuaranteeBean.deleteDocument()}"
        disabled="#{(learningGuaranteeBean.activeEntry.statusCode ne 3) and (learningGuaranteeBean.activeEntry.statusCode ne null)}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener
            target="#{learningGuaranteeBean.selectedDocument}"
            value="#{doc}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
        <h:graphicImage value="../images/icons/delete.gif"></h:graphicImage>
    </h:commandLink>
</p:column>
```

But what happens is, when I delete a attached file, the entire jsf page is reloaded, so the data which are entered in the input fields disappear when I remove the attached file. Could anyone assist me to prevent this please?

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question, but with modern EL versions you don't need the `f:setPropertyActionListener`. You can just pass a parameter to the action method: `action="#{learningGuaranteeBean.deleteDocument(doc)}"`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `h:commandLink` instead of `p:commandLink` by mistake. Since `h:commandLink` doesn't even have the `process`, `update`, `ajax` attributes, this results in a non-AJAX submit, hence the page reload.

Use `p:commandLink`.

If you need `h:commandLink` for some reason, then substitute the erroneous attributes for a proper `f:ajax` tag.